# Spring Cloud Eureka Cluster Setup in AWS using DNS based Elastic Network Interface (ENI)

Tags: amazon-ec2, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to setup eureka cluster in us-east-1 region. There are 2 availability zones (zone b & d), and running an instance of eureka server on each zone. We setup DNS text record which refers to ENI of servers in each zone.

Spring boot version - 2.0.5.RELEASE

Following are more information about environment:

**Zone b:**

```
IP Address - XX.XXX.XXX.250
Hostname - ip-XX-XXX-XXX-250.ec2.internal
ENI IP Address - XX.XXX.XXX.133
ENI hostname - ip-XX-XXX-XXX-133.ec2.internal
```

**Zone d:**

```
IP Address - XX.XXX.XXX.176
Hostname - ip-XX-XXX-XXX-176.ec2.internal
ENI IP Address - XX.XXX.XXX.161
ENI hostname - ip-XX-XXX-XXX-161.ec2.internal
```

**DNS Configuration:**

```
dig -t txt txt.us-east-1.dev-aws.XXXXX.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
txt.us-east-1.dev-aws.XXXXX.com. 300 IN TXT "us-east-1b.dev-aws.XXXXX.com"
txt.us-east-1.dev-aws.XXXXX.com. 300 IN TXT "us-east-1d.dev-aws.XXXXX.com"

nslookup -q=txt txt.us-east-1b.dev-aws.XXXXX.com
Non-authoritative answer:
txt.us-east-1b.dev-aws.XXXXX.com    text = "ip-XX-XXX-XXX-133.ec2.internal"

nslookup -q=txt txt.us-east-1d.dev-aws.XXXXX.com
Non-authoritative answer:
txt.us-east-1d.dev-aws.XXXXX.com    text = "ip-XX-XXX-XXX-161.ec2.internal"
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.eureka-server-u-r-l-context=eureka
eureka.client.region=us-east-1
eureka.client.eureka-server-port=8761
eureka.client.use-dns-for-fetching-service-urls=true
eureka.client.eureka-server-d-n-s-name=dev-aws.XXXXX.com
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.server.binding-strategy=ENI
eureka.datacenter=cloud
eureka.environment=AWS-DEV
```

**SpringEurekaServerAwsApplication.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class SpringEurekaServerAwsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringEurekaServerAwsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils) {
        EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfigBean = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
        AmazonInfo info = AmazonInfo.Builder.newBuilder().autoBuild("eureka");
        eurekaInstanceConfigBean.setDataCenterInfo(info);
        eurekaInstanceConfigBean.setHostname(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.localHostname));
        eurekaInstanceConfigBean.setIpAddress(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.localIpv4));
        return eurekaInstanceConfigBean;
    }   
}
```

I am able to see all instances currently registered in eureka on both instances but available replica is always blank. It looks like an issue in spring cloud eureka server. Could someone help to look into this issue?

Following are the screenshot of eureka dashboard:

**Zone b**
[image]

**Zone d**
[image]

Added in [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3229)

@RyanBaxter Ryan - I am able to see replicated instances in "Instances currently registered with Eureka", but "available-replicas" is blank. Moreover, it is taking time (not consistent, around 30-50 mins) to reflect registered instance in replicas. I can also following in eureka server logs, looks like some configuration is incorrect, but not able to find it.

```
2018-10-12 15:46:52.624  INFO 26564 --- [Eureka-PeerNodesUpdater] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Removing no longer available peer nodes [http://ip-XX-XXX-XXX-161.ec2.internal:8761/eureka/]
2018-10-12 15:46:52.624  INFO 26564 --- [Eureka-PeerNodesUpdater] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http://ip-XX-XXX-XXX-133.ec2.internal:8761/eureka/]

2018-10-12 16:16:52.730  INFO 26564 --- [Eureka-PeerNodesUpdater] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Removing no longer available peer nodes [http://ip-XX-XXX-XXX-133.ec2.internal:8761/eureka/]
2018-10-12 16:16:52.731  INFO 26564 --- [Eureka-PeerNodesUpdater] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http://ip-XX-XXX-XXX-161.ec2.internal:8761/eureka/]
```

One more issue - Eureka is not unbinding ENI during shutdown due to below exception:

```
2018-10-17 14:26:34.756  INFO 2389 --- [Thread-16] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2018-10-17 14:26:34.758  WARN 2389 --- [Thread-16] .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfig': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
```

Comment: In the screenshots I see the replicas, so I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @RyanBaxter Ryan - I am able to see replicated instances in "Instances currently registered with Eureka", but "available-replicas" is blank. Moreover, it is taking time (not consistent, around 30-50 mins) to reflect registered instance in replicas. I can also some weird things in eureka server logs, edited my original post with that, please refer it .

Comment: Eureka must not be able to successfully reach the replicas, I dont see any other reason why it would remove them.

Comment: @RyanBaxter - Another issue - It is not detaching ENI during shutdown, getting below exception.

CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfig': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)

Comment: We need a way to reproduce the errors you are seeing